# How to fix Kotlin compiler error inferred type is () -> Unit but Consumer<Throwable?>? was expected

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following Java method

```
 public Disposable getSuperWifiStatus(SuperWifiProvider provider, Consumer<CPE_SuperWifiStatus>   onNext, Consumer<Throwable> onError) {
    return null;
 }
```

I'm calling that java method from a Kotlin class file like this:

```
 communicationManager.getSuperWifiStatus(
                SuperWifiProvider.AIRTIES,
                { emitter.onNext(status)},
                { emitter.onError(it)}
```

This compiles and works.

If I convert the java method to Kotlin function:

```
  fun getSuperWifiStatus(provider: SuperWifiProvider?, onNext: Consumer<CPE_SuperWifiStatus?>?,   onError: Consumer<Throwable?>?): Disposable? {
    return null
  }
```

I get the following compiler errors:

```
 1. unresolved reference it 
 2. type mismatch inferred type is () -> Unit
    but Consumer<Throwable?>? was expected
```

I don't know how to solve them

Comment: for 2 you should be able to specify the type of a lambda by doing something like `Consumer<Throwable?> { emitter.onError(it) }`

Comment: great. please, write this as answer, that suggestion also solved 1. thaank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the type of a lambda explicitly by doing:

```
Consumer<Throwable?> { emitter.onError(it) }
```